# sql server log shipping space consumption

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, log-shipping

I have implemented sql server logs shipping from hq to dr server

The secondary databases are in standby mode .

The issue is that after configuring it , my dr server is running out of space very rapidly

I have checked the log shipping folders where the trn files resides and they are of very decent size , and the retention is configured for twenty four hours

I checked the secondary databases and their size is exactly same as that of the corresponding primary databases

Could you guys please help me out in identifying the reason behind this odd space increase

I would be grateful if you could point me to some online resources that explains this matter with depth.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see how the transaction files are managed on the primary and secondary.  There is a copy job that ships the backup leaving you with a transaction log backup on the primary and secondary.  Check to make sure that your retention policy on both are set to 24 hours.  Also, there is an initial backup that gets created and you might want to make sure that was deleted after you initialized the log shipping process.

I would also make verify that the log file on the primary is maintained often enough so that you aren't getting unnecessarily large transaction backups.

But, if you're on top of all that already, try and use a tool like WinDirStat to see what files on the server are taking up the most disk space.  You may uncover something not directly related to log shipping (page file, maybe?)

https://windirstat.info/